# Is there a way to force pixellate the viewport render?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, interface, resolution, pixel-art

I occasionally use blender for pixelart by disabling interpolation, mipmaps and anti-aliasing in render options, but it would be great to see how a model is looking without having to render it everytime.

The render preview in the viewport only comes in one resolution, and it would be great to view it in the exact dimensions or just overall look as the final render. is such a thing possible?

Here's a render with the look I'm going for side by side with the viewport view in render mode.

[image]

Comment: I've created a related question about Eevee since these options are not available for it: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/188023/1958

Comment: Captain, do you think this question is about pixel art? I've created a tag for it but some mods doubt it's needed. I'd like to know you thoughts on this.

Comment: I think it does apply, I used it for pixel art in the end. the viewport tweak was needed to preview it without rendering it every time.

Comment: Ok, I've added it to the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your viewport resolution.

*Render Tab > Performance > Viewport > Pixel Size*

[image]

Comment: It worked a charm. thank you

Comment: Happy to help :).