# Pixelate the viewport camera in Eevee for previewing live pixel art / low-resolution render?

Tags: camera, eevee-render-engine, pixel-art

Related question that covered only Cycles: [Is there a way to force pixellate the viewport render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/164678/1958)
These options are not available for Eevee. Is it possible with Eevee? Render sizes are 32x32, 16x16, 20x20 and 32x64. Right now I have to add a grid foreground to camera to get estimation of what pixels will look like:
[image: screenshot]

Rendered example:

[image: pixelated hammer]

Comment: Why can't you just render at a low resolution?

Comment: @EricXue That's exactly what I do now, but I want to get rid of rendering step and preview the render in the camera.

Comment: Discussion about pixel-art tag moved to https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2727/1958

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to be using blender 4 or greater I think for the real time compositor. Worked well enough to preview the pixel art look. Not exact as the pixel size will change with your zoom level, but at least you'll be able to control it.

[image: Compositor node graph for pixelated preview]

Comment: Thanks for the posts. This is not a regular forum, according to site rules [links to answers are not answers](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382) if the link goes missing your answer becomes an empty shell without content. Answers should be substantial and stand on their own without relying on external data like links, videos or images. Instead of having users go through external links, either transcribe essential parts of the process here, linking the source, or posts these in the comments section instead.

Comment: Sorry about that, thanks for the heads up. Posting the link here then.

I got the node graph from a CGmatter video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEfQXRtqzF0)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it when the war ends.